# How do I convert strings in code to uppercase in Visual Studio?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, uppercase

I'm trying to convert all character strings that match a particular regex in a file to uppercase, but I can't find the syntax to specify that within the 'Find and replace' window in Visual Studio. Is it possible to do this using the Visual Studio regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As JaredPar has expained, this cannot be done using a generic regular expression search/replace. However, I guess you should be able to do this using a [macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: macro seems to be a good tool for the task: 1) search with Ctr+F for the first entry 2) get to the beginning of file and start recording (Ctrl+Shift+R) 3) do first conversion (F3, Ctrl+Shift+U, Right) 4) stop recording 5) run macro till it hits end of file (hold Ctrl+Shift+P)

Comment: [Adding macro support for VS2012/2013/2015](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13353364/1548895)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do this as a generic replacement using Visual Studio regular expressions.  It is possible to re-use the captured text as part of a replacement string using the \n escape sequence where n represents the nth group of captured text.  However the regex language only supports limited modifications on this text (mostly justification changes).  It doesn't allow you to change case.

Here is a link to the Visual Studio regex language

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

press alt + 'e' when the find window has focus to enable "regex" searches.

naturally, you can't 'program' a set of replacement options to insert based on what is found. Each replacement set would require one pass.